# Initialization within Unit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm new to Java and working my way through unit testing with JUnit. I was curious if it is bad practice to initialize objects inside each particular test vice just once at the beginning of the test class if only to save ones self from repeating code. For instance:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void defaultObj() {
        Obj d = new Obj();
        String name = "";
        assertEquals(name, d.getName());
    }
```

vs

```
public class MyTest {
    Obj d = new Obj();
    String name = "";    

    @Test
    public void defaultObj() {
        assertEquals(name, d.getName());
    }
```

Again, assuming I have more than one unit test, and I would be calling `Obj d = new Obj();` in every single one of them. I feel as though the latter is more appropriate. However, I thought the former to be more explicit as each intiailizaton is localize (right?) and should I have more than one constructor for `Obj`, my intializations in the beginning will start to stack.

Is there a best practices idiom here? Or is either acceptable?

Comment: The second example is better given that you will be calling the constructor in every unit test method.

Comment: @alayor Right, I thought calling it over and over seemed a bit ridiculous.

Comment: You may also consider looking at Spock once you have a general idea of how JUnit works. It actually runs on top of JUnit but also provides a lot of syntactic convenience, including automatically reinitializing fields (e.g., `String name = randomName()`) for each test case.

Comment: All styles of initialization have the advantages and drawbacks. There is no best practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to share member variables among unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706008/is-it-a-good-practice-to-share-member-variables-among-unit-tests)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best you can do is declare the object you're going to test (in this case `Obj`) at the class level. Then, call the constructor inside the `@Before` method.

It would be better to declare the `name` property inside the method as I assume it won't be used in every method.

```
public class MyTest {
  private Obj d;

  @Before
  public void defaultObj() {
    d = new Obj();
  }

  @Test
  public void defaultObj() {
    String name = "";
    assertEquals(name, d.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I make an `@After` call to clear up memory by deleting the created objects each time?

Comment: You don't need to. The Garbage Collector will do the job.

Comment: @datta And that's a Big Thing if you're coming to Java from a language like C++; unless an object holds an external resource (like a window handle), it's not customary to delete them. I routinely write entire Web applications with no cleanup code at all (other than the built-in shutdown handlers).

Comment: @chrylis Yes. From C++ to Python to Java. Everybody handles the memory addressing and cleanup differently. Drives me bonkers...

Comment: @datta The languages have different niches. Note that in Java, heavy use of runtime reflection is characteristic of most useful frameworks and toolsets, which makes it great for business-style applications (lots of stuff can be implicit and solved for by the runtime). On the other hand, I'm getting into some concurrent embedded programming now, and coming back to C++ after 15 years is like entering the Twilight Zone!

Comment: Avoid/minimise use of member variables in test class. Use local variables inside the test methods as much as possible. It will make each test more independent/separate/self-contained
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706008/is-it-a-good-practice-to-share-member-variables-among-unit-tests?rq=3

Answer (score 0):

You can use JUnit annotations like @Before and @After

```
public class MyTest {

Obj d;
String name;

@Before
public void setup() {
  d = new Obj();
  name = "";    
}

@Test
public void defaultObj() {
    assertEquals(name, d.getName());
}
```

Comment: Those annotations mean the method gets executed each time right? So I have `@Before`, `@Test` #1 and `@Test` #2; `@Before` gets executed, the #1, `@Befor`e again, then #2?

Comment: @datta Yes. `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` are executed once, `@Before` and `@After` for each test. Note that you should name your methods something sensible but that the annotations are what the framework is looking for.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to declare `name` at class level.